# Android Studio add flutter sdk path in preferences

Tags: android-studio, flutter, dart

I just started app programming and I wanted to do so using flutter. But when I want to create a new flutter project, it takes eternal and doesn't finish. Tried all fixed, updating flutter and AS, running AS in Admin Mode (btw I'm using Win 10), creating the project offline, not doing so, reinstalling AS in a folder with a dart-compliant name, but one option I can't try: in the settings for new projects I can't set the standard path of the flutter and dart sdk. If anyone knows how to fix this, or, even better, how to create a flutter project, please describe it step by step, since I'm a complete beginner to app programming

Comment: did you install flutter sdk ?

Comment: Yup, "flutter doctor" reported no issues both from the main and the flutter directory

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One solution was just running the `flutter create` command. Although it kind of worked offline, I finally decided to create the flutter project online. Afterwards I opened it in AS without a problem or missing/corrupted files (so the issue should be with AS and flutter together). And even if it's kind of a workaround, it worked for me.

This is what I typed in the console:

```
flutter create --pub --no-offline --with-driver-test --template=app --description="Your description here." --org="yourdomainhere" --project-name="your_project_name_here" C:\src\flutter\flutter_projects\your_flutter_project
```

Answer (score 2):

Try out this step manually in android studio :

[image: flutter_sdk_path]

Comment: The options "Flutter" and "Dart" above "Kotlin" are missing in my settings for new projects, as I said

Comment: @VincentGuttmann Okay try Invalidate Cashes/Restart your android studio

Comment: I restarted AS and my PC but nothing changed

Comment: @VincentGuttmann can you please attach some screenshots of which plugin you are installed and also settings of your android studio?

Comment: Which settings specifically? There are a ton of them, so I want to pick the important ones

Answer (score 1):

Did you follow the guidelines correctly when creating a new Flutter project? 
Please follow this link step by step https://flutter.dev/docs/development/tools/android-studio

Comment: I did so until the "Creating Flutter Project" Text showed up. Now I'm once again stuck here. Before I also tried to create a project not from the "Welcome"-Screen but from the editor itself. Same result.

Answer (score 0):

For those viewing this question in 2021 and onwards, you need to do the following to get Flutter (version 2) to work in Android Studio (version 4<) on Windows.

1. Download and extract the Flutter SDK. See https://flutter.dev/docs/get-started/install/windows
2. Include path/to/flutter-sdk/bin in your path (System Properties -> Environment Variables)
3. Install the flutter plugin in Android Studio
4. Create a project and provide the SDK path (without /bin at the end)